# Get `parse_date_time` to recognize single digit minutes

Tags: r, lubridate

I can't seem to find the right option for `lubridate`'s `parse_date_time` to recognize a single digit minute. Here is my use case.

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(hm("18 10"), "HMS")
#[1] "0000-01-01 18:10:00 UTC"
parse_date_time(hm("18 09"), "HMS")
#[1] NA
#Warning message:
#All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

More broadly, I'm trying to plot by time of day (stripping out the date), so if there's a better way to do this, I'd love to know.

Comment: An alternative : `as.POSIXct("18 09", format = "%H %M")` but not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, d.b. That works! So does the orders argument just use the formats in the list until it finds one that works? Could I do it with only the "%H %M" format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(x = "18 09", orders = c("HMS", "%H %M"))
```

"The `parse_date_time` allows the user to specify several format-orders to handle heterogeneous date-time character representations." That means that the function will look through the orders to find one that works to parse with.

Answer (score 0):

how about below code to solve your broader problem?

```
dts = seq(as.POSIXct("2018-07-21"), as.POSIXct("2018-07-22") , by=60)
pr_dts = paste(sprintf("%.2d",hour(dts)),sprintf("%.2d",minute(dts)),sep=":")
head(pr_dts);
```

Comment: Thanks, MSW Data. I was thinking I would need them in a time format rather than just character in order to plot them properly, no?